Spring Boot Validation and Generics
I have a class that implements generics:
public abstract class BasicServices<DTO, CONTROLLER extends IController>{

   
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(value = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public DTO add(@RequestBody DTO dto, Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
         return getController().create(dto, authentication.getName());
   }

   ....
}

This class implements some basic REST methods that are common to any of my REST services: add, remove, update, delete, and so on.
I have multiples classes, that inherits the previous class. As an example:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarServices extends BasicServices<CarDTO, CarController> {
}

When executing the application, CarService inherits all methods from the parent and the REST for creating, removing, etc. are available as expected.
Now I want to use Jakarta Validations for Validate the CarDTO content. I have included on the pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

And updated the methods as:
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(value = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public DTO add(@Valid @RequestBody DTO dto, Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
         return getController().create(dto, authentication.getName());
   }

Where I put the @Valid on the generic DTO parameter. And I add on the CarDTO a simple validation:
public class CarDTO {

    @NotBlank
    private String name = "";
}

Last, I have extended the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler to catch the validation error, and convert to a BAD_REQUEST error:
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, @NotNull final HttpHeaders headers, @NotNull final HttpStatusCode status, @NotNull final WebRequest request) {
    ....
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorMessage("Not valid field!), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

I have created a test, where intentionally I am calling the endpoint and sending a CarDTO with an empty name, but not validation error is obtained. I receive a 201, and not a 400 code.
Thinks that I have also tested:

Adding @Validated on class level as suggested somewhere on StackOverflow. Tried on each of CarServices and BasicServices and both of them, without any change.
Overriding the add method on CarService and add the @Valid annotation there. But I cannot do this, as is registered as a new endpoint with the same URL.

Does it means that validations are not working on generics? or I am doing something wrong?
** UPDATE **
Ok, I have tested, as recommended by the comments, to create a REST method and validate the payload. A simple method without using generics.
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/cars")
    public class CarServices extends BasicServices<CarDTO, CarController> {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(value = "/new-car", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public CarDTO addNew(@Valid @RequestBody CarDTO dto, Authentication authentication) {
        return getController().create(dto);
    }
}

The method addNew now is not inherited and neither is using generics. Maybe the issue is elsewhere?

"But I cannot do this, as is registered as a new endpoint with the same URL." you have to remove @PostMapping from base class for it to work.

Just to make sure: what is full class name of Valid annotation?

The class is jakarta.validation.Valid and for validated org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated.

Yes, I need to remove the @PostMapping, but that means that I need to override in all inner classes to defined the endpoint. I would prefer to have a generic method with the @Valid, where any payload can have its own validated parameters

It should work, this annotation is processed in runtime. Does it work if you put method in derived class?

Let me check. It is not quick as I have multiple classes.

You only need to try it on one method.

No, not working. That probably means that the issue can be elsewhere. I will update the question with the new information.

What is FQN of @NotBlank?

It is jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank.
